# Find the equation of the parabola that contains points (1,10) & (2,4), has a vertical axis of symmetry, and whose vertex is on the line $4x-3y=6$.

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Find the equation of the parabola which contains the points $(1,10)$ and $(2,4)$, has a vertical axis of symmetry and whose vertex is on the line $4x-3y=6$.

I'm not sure how to go about this. I feel there is not enough information.

What approach should be taken here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two equations $$a+b+c=10$$
and $$4a+2b+c=4$$ and since the vertex is on the line
$$y=\frac{4}{3}x-2$$ the equation
$$\frac{4ac-b^2}{4ac}=\frac{4}{3}\cdot \left(-\frac{b}{2a}\right)-2$$

Answer (score 1):

You are right, there doesn't seem to be enough information. There actually exist two parabolas that work:

$$ y = 2(x-3)^2 + 2 $$
$$ y = 26(x - \frac{21}{13})^2 + \frac{2}{13} $$

You can get these results by using the vertex formula for the parabola

$$ y = a(x-d)^2 + e $$

where $(d,e)$ is the vertex and $a$ is a stretching factor. Thus, the provided information gives us the following

$$ a(d-1)^2 + e = 10 $$
$$ a(d-2)^2 + e = 4 $$
$$ 4d - 3e = 6 $$

Full solution:

> Subtracting the first two equations yields 
>
> $$a = \frac{6}{2d-3} $$
>
> and the third equation yields 
>
> $$ e = \frac{4}{3}d - 2 $$
>
> So substitute $a$ and $e$ in 
>
> $$ a(d-1)^2 + e = 10 $$
>
> to get 
>
> $$ \frac{6}{2d-3} (d-1)^2 + \frac{4}{3}d - 2 = 10 . $$
>
> After simplifying, this becomes a quadratic 
>
> $$ \frac{26}{3}d^2 - 40d + 42 = 0 $$
>
> which has solutions $d = \frac{21}{3}$ and $d = 3$. Plug these back in to get the respective values for $e$ and $a$. As it turns out, both produce valid parabolas. 
>
> Thus, there are two such parabolas. One with vertex $(3,2)$ and one with vertex $(\frac{21}{13}, \frac{2}{13})$.